# Update the UI of the calling activity or start a new activity when the alarm is triggered from a broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I am writing an alarm code and using a broadcast receiver. I am able to receive the broadcast receiver. but now I want to come back to the calling activity and update the UI of my activity. I am not able to this. 
I used the following code in my activity but it is never executing that code.

```
 private BroadcastReceiver myBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "I am back!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  };


  @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("com.test.Main");
        registerReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
    }
```

in the manifest file I have included the following, here gotAlarm is the broadcast receiver file

```
   <receiver android:name=".gotAlarm"
        android:enabled="true">
        </receiver>
```

gotAlarm file is one which gets called from the pending intent of the alarm set

```
public class gotAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    Toast.makeText(context, "Wake Up!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }
 }
```

May be I am missing something very basic. 
please help.

Comment: This is an alarm code and I am trying to update the UI of the activity if it is in the foreground. If it is not then it should update itself whenever it is opened and certain condition is fulfilled. right now I am concentrating in the first part that is, it should update the UI whenever there is an alarm time. I know this is doable as many people might have done it successfully. But I am at a fix here :-|

Comment: When I am launching my application for the first time then I see that the onResume() method is getting called. After that when the alarm comes neither onPause() nor onResume is getting called.

Comment: I have changed my approach now. As I did not find it running :-| Now I am sending data from activity to broadcast and then from this broadcast I am launching a new activity and passing the data on to this new activity. I will post the code soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have dropped this way and I am starting a new activity on receiving broadcast. And I am sending information data from calling activity to broadcast and from broadcast to next activity. This has served the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. If you dynamically register the receiver via Context.registerReceiver() then you won't receive broadcasts when Activity is paused (or stopped or not-running). If you need to receive broadcasts even when Activity is paused then create a top-level BroadcastReceiver class (as opposed to your inner class) and use `<receiver>` to register it.
2. BroadcastReceiver lifecycle [docs state](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle) that BroadcastReceiver object is alive only during processing of `onReceive()`. You can not do any async tasks like showing dialogs, etc.. In your case (Activities might not be running and you receive a broadcast) you should use NotificationManager to notify user something happened.

Comment: "then create a top-level BroadcastReceiver class (as opposed to your inner class) " I got it but can you please provide any sample code for this?

Comment: I am already using the <register> tag in the manifest. I think you understood my problem well. as the even when the activity is paused I need to get the Toast I have written in the example.

Comment: Can you pls post contents of your `<receiver>` tag?

Comment: You have a class named `gotAlarm` which is a subclass of BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: yes the class gotAlarm extends from broadcastreceiver. I have edited my code again.

Comment: Does this get called when broadcast happens? Anyhow, you can not show Toast if you activity is not active: you can not show a Toast if some other app is active. You should use NotificationManager.

Comment: yes, it is getting called I am able to see toast and you are right I have to add notification, toast is only for testing purpose. I am even able to play a .ogg file from here.

Comment: do u also feel that the problem i am having with my code is very trivial as the code looks fine??

Comment: If you need to update the Activity when it is visible and a broadcast is received, then try to save a reference to this activity in Application. Set the reference in `onResume()` and clear it in 'onPause()`. Then check if the reference is set (if it is this means that Activity is active, i.e. it's visible) and use it to change this Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Did you [register your BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter%29) (you can do this in the 'onResume'-method of your Activity)? Also, you should [unregister your BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unregisterReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver%29) in the 'onPause'-method.

Comment: @Lucas: I have done the register and unregister but no luck :(

Comment: hey do I have to add any more code in the onPause() and onResume() code?

Comment: The 'onPause' e.g. 'onResume'-methods from the super class need to be called.